# Understanding Template Partial Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand the concept of partial specialization of templates. However I seem to be confusing it with template specialization. I am considering the following two examples

```
template <typename T> 
struct test
{
   ///Some stuff
};

template <> //Specialization
struct test<int*>
{
   ///Some stuff
};


template<typename t> //Partial specialization
struct test<t*>
{
   ///Some stuff
};
```

I am trying the following

```
test<int*> s;
```

and this calls the specialized template. How can i call the partially specialized class. Could anyone please also explain the difference between partial and specialized template with an example ?

**Update:**

After going through the answers I realized that partial template specialization assists only when a subset of the parameters need to be specialized. So I tried something like this

```
template <>
struct test<int*>
{
};


//Partial Specialized
template<typename t>
struct test<t, std::string>
{
};

test<int*,std::string> s;  //Error : Too many arguments for class template
```

Why is that ?

Comment: no, partial specialization is when you provide another implementation of a general template, explicitly precising one or more types. That's not what you're doing here. What you comment as partial specialization is indeed the general template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make things short, when talking about class templates :

- [Explicit (Full) Specialization :](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) all templates arguments are specified
- [Partial specialization :](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) customize the template by specifying only a subset of the templates arguments

**Example of all 3 cases:**

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U> //Primary template
struct test
{
   void foo() { std::cout << "\nPrimary"; }
};

template <typename T> //Specialization
struct test<T, int*>
{
   void foo() { std::cout << "\nPartial Specialization"; }
};


template<> //Full specialization
struct test<int*, int*>
{
   void foo() { std::cout << "\nFull Specialization"; }
};

int main()
{
    test<int, double> t1;
    t1.foo();
    
    test<double, int*> t2;
    t2.foo();
    
    test<int*, int*> t3;
    t3.foo();
}
```

Output :

> Primary
>
> Partial Specialization
>
> Full Specialization

**[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/059ad2872380b87e)**

---

To answer your update :

- A template specialization cant add arguments, it can only specialize existing arguments

Comment: I think your specialization is wrong . it is suppose to have a `template <>`

Comment: @Rajeshwar the comment was wrong, the code is correct (see th live demo)

Comment: @Rajeshwar no, and that is the point of my answer. a partial specialization only specify some arguments, whereas a full (`template<>`) specify **all** arguments . Hope it helps.

Comment: I just updated my question. Could you kindly update your answer

Comment: you can partially specialize `template<class T> myclass{};` with `template<class U> myclass<std::vector<U>>{};` so the last sentence is wrong

Answer (score 2):

There are two effects which can be achieved with partial specialisation.

One, you can "fix" one or more template parameters to concrete values, while keeping the others "unbound." Here's an example:

```
template <class A, class B>
struct Foo  // The primary template
{
  static const int i = 0;
};

template <class A>
struct Foo<A, int>  // Partial specialisation which "fixes" B
{
  static const int i = 1;
};

template <>
struct Foo<char, int>  // Full specialisation
{
  static const int i = 2;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << Foo<char, double>::i;  // 0
  std::cout << Foo<double, int>::i << Foo<void, int>::i;  // 11
  std::cout << Foo<char, int>::i;  //2
}
```

Two, you can provide an alternative definition for the template for a more specific version of a (still generic) template parameter:

```
template <class A>
struct Bar  // Primary template
{
  static const int i = 0;
};

template <class A>
struct Bar<A*>  // Patrial specialisation for pointers
{
  static const int i = 1;
};

template <>
struct Bar<int*>  // Full specialisation
{
  static const int i = 2;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << Bar<int>::i;  // 0
  std::cout << Bar<void*>::i << Bar<int**>::i;  // 11
  std::cout << Bar<int*>::i;  // 2
}
```

This is precisely what your original code is doing.

You can of course also combine the two, like this:

```
template <class A>
struct Foo<std::vector<A>, int>  // Partial specialisation of primary Foo from above, for any std::vector and an int
{
  static const int i = 3;
};
```

Comment: in the last example the primary template must have two parameters correct ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar Yes, I was using the `Foo` from part 1 of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a template:

```
tempalte <typename A, typename B>
class Foo {};
```

And you can specialize it:

```
template <>
class Foo<int, int> {};
```

You might also leave one of the parameters free (partial specialization):

```
template <typename B>
class Foo<std::string, B> {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) regarding template specialization.

```
template <>
```

Will be the way you handle a specific type, while

```
template<typename t> //Partial specialization
struct test<t*>
```

Is how you handle generic types.  Of couse

```
test<int*> s;
```

calls the specialized template, because that is what you specified above.  To call the partially specialized, call with any other type for the template.  For example

```
test<char*> s;
```